# Can't combine strpos and !empty in PHP, why?

Tags: php

I have two lines in PHP that if I combine causes my page to stop loading...Unfortunately, I have no error message using `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`, and nothing in my apache error.log file.

**this works:**

```
$user_setup = strpos($_SESSION['user'], "@");
if (!empty($user_setup)) {....
```

**But, this does not:**

```
if (!empty(strpos($_SESSION['user'], "@"))) {....
```

Is there something about the `strpos` function causing this to not work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) expects a variable, not just a value. But you should use `$user_setup !== false` in this case anyway as `strpos` returns `0` for the case the *needle* is at the begin of the string.

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks @Gumbo

Do you know of any function that could replace !empty in this case? (p.s. feel free to submit yours as an answer)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `strpos` always returns a value, so checking it with `empty` isn't that much usefull. You should use some explicit condition instead, like `0 === strpos(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[empty()](http://php.net/empty) is actually a language construct not a function. Additionally it won't take anything less than a variable as an argument.

Comment: as of php 5.5(unreleased), empty doesn't require a variable anymore.

Comment: Unreleased means irrelevant in this case.